# Get details of changed record using Sql Dependency

Tags: c#, sql, sqldependency

I'm using [Sql Dependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to notify changes when they occur. But is there any way that I can identify the ID of a particular record(s) that has changed.

Here is the dependency change callback function which I'm using right now.

```
    private static void onDependencyChange(Object o, SqlNotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        //
    }
```

In both the callback arguments, I can't find anything which would give details about the changed record. Does anyone know of a solution or a work around ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14877751/1048425) would suggest that you can't get the record(s) that have changed. The suggested workaround is a `ModifiedDateTime` field, then you would need to retrieve rows modified after a certain point.

Comment: Is there any official documentation which says that we cant get changed records details using SQL Dependency ?

Comment: There is the documentation for [SqlNotificationEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it does not list the things you can't get from it (this would be a fairly exhaustive list), but it does list the things you obtain from it, and the data that has changed is not one of the things that you can retrieve.

Comment: I am curious if the data cannot be retrieved (so what is the sql dependecy used for ... In oracle - the sql dependency can retrieve the rowid, and I at least can know which record exactly changed.